# What is the best practice to define props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

What is the best practice to define props in a component class in React.js? And why?

Inside the class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    prop: PropTypes
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> </div>
    )
  }
};
```

or outside the class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div> </div>
        )
    }
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    prop: PropTypes
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second option.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div> </div>
        )
    }
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    prop: PropTypes
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Check [Clean Code vs. Dirty Code: React Best Practices](https://americanexpress.io/clean-code-dirty-code/) for reference.

Comment: If you downvote this answer, please have the courtesy to write down the reason in the comment.

Comment: I have downvote this answer as it is no difference between those two, and the question as well as the answer is only fully opinion based. The real answer is to be consistent and choose one of these two. But not that second is better in any kind.

Comment: Then you should block the question and not downvote the answer. Also, I have added a link to write cleaner code. Code conventions are not opinion based. We follow some standards. If you have few rights please use them wisely. I don't say that you should not downvote. I am saying if you are downvoting the answer then you must know the correct answer. Please go ahead and post the correct one. I would be very happy to know where I was wrong. Please don't take it to heart. Just saying what I feel.

Comment: Although it is a matter of opinion, it is considered better practice to keep the propTypes outside of the component as it reduces clutter inside of the component. This is also used as example usage section of the prop-types package.